# Как перебрать многомерный массив php?

Tags: php, массивы

Дан такой массив

```
$array = array(
'name' => 'font-weight',
'type' => 'select',
'options'=> array(
    'bold'=>'Bold',
    'normal'=>'Normal'
));
```

Как вывести все значения 'options'. То есть должно получиться

```
Bold 
Normal
```

Comment: А с чем у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: `echo $array['options']['bold'];
echo $array['options']['normal'];` или пройти циклом по массиву `$array['options']` или объединить элементы `echo join(' ', $array['options']);`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но я бы хотел перебрать через foreach, $key => $value. Это возможно? Потому что ключи будут меняться.

Comment: [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/98958d5fb90ee26597e5c3e0e19ef5a58a5d23b2)

Comment: То, что я хотел. Спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    'name' => 'font-weight',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options'=> array(
        'bold'=>'Bold',
        'normal'=>'Normal'
    )
);

foreach ($array['options'] as $opt) {
    var_dump($opt);
}
```